# Can't get "time ago" date format to work

Tags: 7, datetime

From this blog post http://drupalmotion.com/article/time-ago-date-format-drupal

Function:

```
/**
 * Format date implementing hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  $vars['date'] = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'M jS, Y');
  $vars['time_ago'] = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'c'); // 'c' is the ISO 8601 date format. Since PHP 5
}
```

Markup:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="<?php print $time_ago; ?>"><?php print $date; ?></abbr>
```

with the jQuery TimeAgo plugin loaded.

```
/**
 * Timeago is a jQuery plugin that makes it easy to support automatically
 * updating fuzzy timestamps (e.g. "4 minutes ago" or "about 1 day ago").
 *
 * @name timeago
 * @version 1.4.1
 * @requires jQuery v1.2.3+
 * @author Ryan McGeary
 * @license MIT License - http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * For usage and examples, visit:
 * http://timeago.yarp.com/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Ryan McGeary (ryan -[at]- mcgeary [*dot*] org)
 */

(function (factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(jQuery);
  }
}(function ($) {
  $.timeago = function(timestamp) {
    if (timestamp instanceof Date) {
      return inWords(timestamp);
    } else if (typeof timestamp === "string") {
      return inWords($.timeago.parse(timestamp));
    } else if (typeof timestamp === "number") {
      return inWords(new Date(timestamp));
    } else {
      return inWords($.timeago.datetime(timestamp));
    }
  };
  var $t = $.timeago;

  $.extend($.timeago, {
    settings: {
      refreshMillis: 60000,
      allowPast: true,
      allowFuture: false,
      localeTitle: false,
      cutoff: 0,
      strings: {
        prefixAgo: null,
        prefixFromNow: null,
        suffixAgo: "ago",
        suffixFromNow: "from now",
        inPast: 'any moment now',
        seconds: "less than a minute",
        minute: "about a minute",
        minutes: "%d minutes",
        hour: "about an hour",
        hours: "about %d hours",
        day: "a day",
        days: "%d days",
        month: "about a month",
        months: "%d months",
        year: "about a year",
        years: "%d years",
        wordSeparator: " ",
        numbers: []
      }
    },

    inWords: function(distanceMillis) {
      if(!this.settings.allowPast && ! this.settings.allowFuture) {
          throw 'timeago allowPast and allowFuture settings can not both be set to false.';
      }

      var $l = this.settings.strings;
      var prefix = $l.prefixAgo;
      var suffix = $l.suffixAgo;
      if (this.settings.allowFuture) {
        if (distanceMillis < 0) {
          prefix = $l.prefixFromNow;
          suffix = $l.suffixFromNow;
        }
      }

      if(!this.settings.allowPast && distanceMillis >= 0) {
        return this.settings.strings.inPast;
      }

      var seconds = Math.abs(distanceMillis) / 1000;
      var minutes = seconds / 60;
      var hours = minutes / 60;
      var days = hours / 24;
      var years = days / 365;

      function substitute(stringOrFunction, number) {
        var string = $.isFunction(stringOrFunction) ? stringOrFunction(number, distanceMillis) : stringOrFunction;
        var value = ($l.numbers && $l.numbers[number]) || number;
        return string.replace(/%d/i, value);
      }

      var words = seconds < 45 && substitute($l.seconds, Math.round(seconds)) ||
        seconds < 90 && substitute($l.minute, 1) ||
        minutes < 45 && substitute($l.minutes, Math.round(minutes)) ||
        minutes < 90 && substitute($l.hour, 1) ||
        hours < 24 && substitute($l.hours, Math.round(hours)) ||
        hours < 42 && substitute($l.day, 1) ||
        days < 30 && substitute($l.days, Math.round(days)) ||
        days < 45 && substitute($l.month, 1) ||
        days < 365 && substitute($l.months, Math.round(days / 30)) ||
        years < 1.5 && substitute($l.year, 1) ||
        substitute($l.years, Math.round(years));

      var separator = $l.wordSeparator || "";
      if ($l.wordSeparator === undefined) { separator = " "; }
      return $.trim([prefix, words, suffix].join(separator));
    },

    parse: function(iso8601) {
      var s = $.trim(iso8601);
      s = s.replace(/\.\d+/,""); // remove milliseconds
      s = s.replace(/-/,"/").replace(/-/,"/");
      s = s.replace(/T/," ").replace(/Z/," UTC");
      s = s.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)\:?(\d\d)/," $1$2"); // -04:00 -> -0400
      s = s.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)$/," $100"); // +09 -> +0900
      return new Date(s);
    },
    datetime: function(elem) {
      var iso8601 = $t.isTime(elem) ? $(elem).attr("datetime") : $(elem).attr("title");
      return $t.parse(iso8601);
    },
    isTime: function(elem) {
      // jQuery's `is()` doesn't play well with HTML5 in IE
      return $(elem).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() === "time"; // $(elem).is("time");
    }
  });

  // functions that can be called via $(el).timeago('action')
  // init is default when no action is given
  // functions are called with context of a single element
  var functions = {
    init: function(){
      var refresh_el = $.proxy(refresh, this);
      refresh_el();
      var $s = $t.settings;
      if ($s.refreshMillis > 0) {
        this._timeagoInterval = setInterval(refresh_el, $s.refreshMillis);
      }
    },
    update: function(time){
      var parsedTime = $t.parse(time);
      $(this).data('timeago', { datetime: parsedTime });
      if($t.settings.localeTitle) $(this).attr("title", parsedTime.toLocaleString());
      refresh.apply(this);
    },
    updateFromDOM: function(){
      $(this).data('timeago', { datetime: $t.parse( $t.isTime(this) ? $(this).attr("datetime") : $(this).attr("title") ) });
      refresh.apply(this);
    },
    dispose: function () {
      if (this._timeagoInterval) {
        window.clearInterval(this._timeagoInterval);
        this._timeagoInterval = null;
      }
    }
  };

  $.fn.timeago = function(action, options) {
    var fn = action ? functions[action] : functions.init;
    if(!fn){
      throw new Error("Unknown function name '"+ action +"' for timeago");
    }
    // each over objects here and call the requested function
    this.each(function(){
      fn.call(this, options);
    });
    return this;
  };

  function refresh() {
    //check if it's still visible
    if(!$.contains(document.documentElement,this)){
      //stop if it has been removed
      $(this).timeago("dispose");
      return this;
    }

    var data = prepareData(this);
    var $s = $t.settings;

    if (!isNaN(data.datetime)) {
      if ( $s.cutoff == 0 || Math.abs(distance(data.datetime)) < $s.cutoff) {
        $(this).text(inWords(data.datetime));
      }
    }
    return this;
  }

  function prepareData(element) {
    element = $(element);
    if (!element.data("timeago")) {
      element.data("timeago", { datetime: $t.datetime(element) });
      var text = $.trim(element.text());
      if ($t.settings.localeTitle) {
        element.attr("title", element.data('timeago').datetime.toLocaleString());
      } else if (text.length > 0 && !($t.isTime(element) && element.attr("title"))) {
        element.attr("title", text);
      }
    }
    return element.data("timeago");
  }

  function inWords(date) {
    return $t.inWords(distance(date));
  }

  function distance(date) {
    return (new Date().getTime() - date.getTime());
  }

  // fix for IE6 suckage
  document.createElement("abbr");
  document.createElement("time");
}));
```

It just prints "May 18th, 2015" which reveals a more specific date when hovered over.

Comment: You could just use the [Timeago module](https://www.drupal.org/project/timeago).
"Includes: An option to turn node created times into timeago dates"

Comment: @Ben If you put your answer in as an answer instead of a comment then James can select it as the correct answer.

Comment: @rooby I didn't have time to add more info/screenshot on the module in question so I felt somebody else might come with a clean answer with more instructions.

Answer (score 2):

For a non-dynamic solution (doesn't change unless the page is refreshed) you can use the [format_interval()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_interval/7) function like this:

```
$vars['time_ago'] = format_interval(REQUEST_TIME - $node->created) . t(' ago');
```

Comment: Didn't know yet about this possible solution, so +1 ! ... While I was looking around I also saw your comment to the question ... and decided to quickly write down what Ben still didn't seem to have time for ... Hope that was OK to do in this case ...

Comment: Yeah I think comment content is fair game if an answer isn't posted in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 1):

The [Timeago](https://www.drupal.org/project/timeago) module (available for both D6 and D7) can be used for this. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> Uses the jQuery [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin to create dynamically updating "time ago" dates. That is, the plugin turns static dates like "October 10, 2011" into "10 minutes ago" and updates the time ago every minute. This allows you to include "time ago" dates in cached content for most users while degrading gracefully for users with JavaScript disabled.
>
> Features included:
>
> - An option to turn node created times into timeago dates
> - An option to turn comment created/changed times into timeago dates
> - Tokens for node created time and comment created/changed times
> - A timeago date formatter option for use with dates anywhere
> - An API to turn any UNIX timestamp into a timeago date

Obviously, in this case you're looking for the feature mentioned in the first bullet above.